# Enable mobile data using Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to enable mobile network using a button in my Flutter App. I am unable to find a plugin that can allow me to do so.

> Enable Mobile Internet (4G)

Please suggest me an answer that allows me to provide this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's not possible on both Android and iOS platforms so you can't do it in Flutter too since it's relying on those platforms. All you can do now is to show a dialog and guide your users to open their mobile data or open the settings app so that users can enable it.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/unanswered/When-connected-to-Wi-Fi-with-mobile-data-enabled-use-more-battery-than-when-connected-to-Wi-Fi-with-mobile-data-disabled

Comment: What is that link? @TrishantPahwa

Comment: Similar to the answer I am trying to find. Just a work around.